# How to label hierarchical entities inside composite entities correctly?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Is it possible to label wrapped composite entites (curly brackets) around hierarchical entities inside of LUIS.ai phrases?

Imagine the following entities:
We have a simple entity:

- Number

We have hierarchical entities:

- Category (Adult, Child, Infant)
- TravelClass (First, Business, Economy)

We have a composity entity named TicketsOrder:

- Number (Simple)
- Category (Hierarchical)
- TravelClass (Hierarchical)

Imagine the following phrase:

"book me 2 adult business tickets to Paris tomorrow on Air France" which maps the intent "Bookflight". It finds "adult" as category, "business". I can label that easily aswell. The problem is, as soon as I label adult not as category but as the explicit adult-category, I cannot wrap the composite entity around. Therefore it is not possible for me to label multiple words as a composite entity if one of the words is labeled as an explicit child-entity of a hierarchical entity.

In Short: ([] is a simple entity, {} is a composite entity)

- Possible: book me [number] [category] [TravelClass] tickets to Paris tomorrow on Air France
- Possible: book me {[number] [category] [TravelClass]} tickets to Paris tomorrow on Air France
- Possible: book me [number] [category-adult] [TravelClass-business] tickets to Paris tomorrow on Air France
- *NOT* possible: book me {[number] [category-adult] [TravelClass-business]} tickets to Paris tomorrow on Air France
  (because category-adult are child-entities of category and TravelClass-business is a child-class of TravelClass and both are inside of TicketsOrder)

This labeling is needed! The phrase-matching of my application is not very good if those aren't matched correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you need to wrap your composite entities first, then label its children entities. It'll be a slight inconvenience for relabeling your example utterances above as you can't assign prebuilt entities to a token, but wrap from `number` to the end of `TravelClass` and you should be fine. For future utterances it should recognize all the children entities successfully.

I removed the labels from this utterance as an example:

[image]

I want to wrap strawberry ice cream in my `DessertsCold` composite entity; first I select strawberry, then I'll select DessertsCold...

[image]

And it'll place a curly bracket at the front of strawberry; my cursor was hovering over cream which is why a grayed-out version closing curly bracket appeared there.

*Edit: For future assistance to others...*

When creating a Composite Entity and supplying it with Hierarchical Entities for children, it is important to realize that simply adding a Hierarchical Entity Parent does not add *its* children. One must add hierarchical children to a composite entity for the children to be recognized.

Screenshot of adding HE-children to a Composite Entity:[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution seems to not work for me. I can neither label a wrapped entity (e.g. TravelClass) as a specific TravelClass (e.g. TravelClass-business) because the ">" in the hovering menu does not react nor can I add the specific TravelClasses to the composite (as child) because the dropdown does not react on clicking TravelClass::TravelClass-business. The only entity I can add as child entity inside of TicketsOrder is the parent-entity TravelClass. Which one of those should I be able to use?

Comment: That's interesting; children entities from hierarchical entities count as separate entities from their parents... Have you added the hierarchical children to your composite entity?

Comment: No, I could not add those child entities to the hierarchical entity. The buttons are just not working in those cases.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment wasn't clear enough; I actually meant to ask if you added the hierarchical children to your composite entity during the setup of the composite entity, not during your utterance labeling.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. I cannot provide a screenshot right now, but I can do neither of both.

Comment: That's a bug, you should be able to do so. I'll forward this issue to the LUIS team to get their assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144964/discussion-between-steven-g-and-simon-k).